# How to convert C# code which calls Post request with authentication to Java?

Tags: java, c#, http-post

**I want to convert the following C# code to java.** **I need help how to use authenticator in java and call post request**

```
public async Task<TransactionResult> ChargeAsync(string merchantId,
    string apiKey, string vivaWalletToken)
{
    var cl = new RestClient("http://demo.vivapayments.com/api/") {
        Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator(merchantId, apiKey)
    };
    var request = new RestRequest("transactions", Method.POST) {
        RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json
    };

    request.AddParameter("PaymentToken", vivaWalletToken);

    var response = await cl.ExecuteTaskAsync<TransactionResult>(request);

    return response.ResponseStatus == ResponseStatus.Completed &&
        response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK ? response.Data : null;
}
```

**I try to call post request in java with the followin code but I get 405 error**. **I think that is logical since I do not use authenticator**

```
String message;
JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
json.put("vivaWalletToken", vivaWalletToken);
message = json.toString();          

HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build(); //Use this instead 
HttpPost request_post = new HttpPost("http://demo.vivapayments.com/api/");
StringEntity params =new StringEntity(message);
request_post.addHeader("content-type", "application/json");
request_post.setEntity(params);
HttpResponse response_post = httpClient.execute(request_post);
HttpEntity resEntity = response_post.getEntity();
```

Comment: In addition to David's answer see for example http://www.baeldung.com/httpclient-4-basic-authentication

Answer (score 1):

From what I can see you are not setting the REST action in your API call. In the c# code you tell it to call `transactions` meaning that you are posting to

> http://demo.vivapayments.com/api/transactions

but in the Java code you are posting to

> http://demo.vivapayments.com/api/

(405 is a `Method Not Allowed` error)

Comment: Thank you! I changed the url and it works but how can I create the authentication with merchantId and apiKey as in C# code? Now I get the message error: 401 {"Message":"Authorization has been denied for this request."}

Comment: You can check @Fildor 's article for that http://www.baeldung.com/httpclient-4-basic-authentication